Lambda getting access denied when trying to copy the data in same bucket
Lambda getting access denied when trying to copy the data in same bucket.
Here is my Bucket Policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::vgi-esf-eng-us-east-1-narwhal-bfb-automated-input/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::vgi-esf-eng-us-east-1-narwhal-bfb-automated-input"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::vgi-esf-eng-us-east-1-narwhal-bfb-automated-input/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EnforceSSL",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::vgi-esf-eng-us-east-1-narwhal-bfb-automated-input/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Restrict Bucket Access",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::vgi-esf-eng-us-east-1-narwhal-bfb-automated-input",
                "arn:aws:s3:::vgi-esf-eng-us-east-1-narwhal-bfb-automated-input/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::551470947100:role/CloudBotRole",
                        "arn:aws:iam::551470947100:role/globalaccess/*",
                        "arn:aws:iam::551470947100:user/globalaccess/*",
                        "arn:aws:iam::551470947100:role/Bamboo-Role-Remote-*",
                        "arn:aws:iam::551470947100:role/FB0-narwhalbfbautomatedmrprivate-ENG-east-1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

I need bucket policy edited.

What do you mean by "trying to copy the data in same bucket"? Can you show us your code and the exact error message?

Rather than granting permissions via a Bucket Policy, you should add the necessary permissions to the IAM Roles. These would be Allow policies.
In general, it is best to avoid using Deny policies since they override Allow policies and can be somewhat confusing. Also, Bucket Policies are typically only used when granting public access or cross-account access. You should not need a Bucket Policy for your particular use-case.
Given your current Bucket Policy, my guess is that one of the two Deny policies is causing your problem. Try temporarily removing them one-at-a-time to figure out which one is preventing your Lambda function from operating as expected.

I guess the answer is here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateSession.html
In short, you need to add s3express:CreateSession action to your policy.
Do not see a reason to copy-paste information from the provided doc.
Good luck!

@Bhaskar Please do not post code blocks in comments. Instead, Edit your Question and add the additional content.

@Bhaskar, I agree with John. These 3 comments do not make sense in general and really difficult for Quick Look and understanding
